# Url is changing automatically for different views in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.NET Core MVC application, I have two subfolders in the `views` folder - one is `Home` and the other is `Menu`.

The `Home` folder contains `Index.cshtml`, and the `Menu` folder contains `topMenu.cshtml`. When I run the application the URL is

```
localhost/****/home/index
```

There is a sidebar where I put a link for `topmenu.cshtml`, when I click the Top Menu, it's opening the `topMenu.cshtml` view and the URL is

```
localhost:*****/Menu/topMenu
```

The problem is if I'm trying to click on the home page after opening the Top Menu the URL of the home page is changing to

```
localhost/****/menu/index
```

Even after I created separate controllers for both Home and Menu where the action result is returning the view. I also have a login page in my application so I set the default route as

```
{controller=Home}/{action=Login}/{id?}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not share the content of your `topmenu.cshtml`, but I guess you did not specify the `asp-controller="Home"` on your anchor tag. It should look something like this:

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
```

You can read more about the anchor tag attributes here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1#anchor-tag-helper-attributes